# Cannot play mp4 videos, decoder missing Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, video, mp4

I am running Linux and when I try to play an mp4 video in Qt I get the following message:

> Warning: "No decoder available for type 'video/x-h264,
>   stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.2,
>   profile=(string)high,
>   codec_data=(buffer)0164002affe100352764002aac34c80780227e5c05b808080a000007d000030d41d0c000e4e00000e4e1d77971a18001c9c00001c9c3aef2e1f088451601000428ee3830,
>   width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)50/1,
>   pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, parsed=(boolean)true'."

The audio is actaully working great but I cannot see the video. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: On Linux Qt uses GStreamer, so you're probably just missing a plugin. Depending on your distro, you may just have to install a package through your package manager.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks!!!